# How to put non-zero column name as the value of another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
master_df = pd.read_csv("https://azeem-learning.s3.amazonaws.com/comapnies_sectors.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
mapping = pd.read_csv("https://azeem-learning.s3.amazonaws.com/mapping.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I have the following two data frames:
1. Companies list, with the sector. companies_df:
[image]

2. standard sector mapping to 9 broad sectors. mapping_df:
   [image]

I want to map the sector of first df to the right column of the second df. 
I tried doing the following merge:

```
master_frame2 = pd.merge(left=master_frame, right=mapping ,
                    how='inner', left_on='primary_sector', right_on='category_list')
```

As expected, I got all colmuns of mapping df into master_frame with 0's and 1's. Following is the screenshot:
[image]

But I want to have the primary_sector column having value from the name of last 9 columns(whichever column has value 1), like this example:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we cannot work with screenshots.

Comment: Please post your data as text. Otherwise we can't reproduce your analysis. Also, you haven't posted what you've tried so far and what errors you encountered.

Comment: Bro please it hurts my eyes.

Comment: I think you are just looking to reverse a `.get_dummies()`. Try `df.stack()`, then `.map` one onto the other.

Comment: I can see 3D, Wireless in Category list in one df and  in name column in the other. Is Manufacturing, Entertainment column values anywhere? Happy to assist

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I have uploaded all these files to S3 for your ref, please check again.

Comment: The files are not downloadable.

Comment: you should be able to download now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can replace the non zero values with column names like

   df1= df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
2. Replace 0's with empty string and then merge the columns like below

   f = f.replace(0, '') f['new'] = f.First+f.Second+f.Three+f.Four

Refer the full code below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Second':[0,1,0,0],'First':[1,0,0,0],'Three':[0,0,1,0],'Four':[0,0,0,1], 'cl': ['3D', 'Wireless','Accounting','cisco']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'pi':['Accounting','cisco','3D','Wireless']})
df1= df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns, df.columns))
f = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right',left_on=['cl'],right_on=['pi'])
f = f.replace(0, '')
f['new'] = f.First+f.Second+f.Three+f.Four
```

df1:

```
In [3]: df1                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[3]: 
   Second  First  Three  Four          cl
0       0  First      0     0          3D
1  Second      0      0     0    Wireless
2       0      0  Three     0  Accounting
3       0      0      0  Four       cisco
```

df2:

```
In [4]: df2                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: 
           pi
0  Accounting
1       cisco
2          3D
3    Wireless
```

Final df will be:

```
In [2]: f                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: 
   Second  First  Three  Four          cl          pi     new
0          First                       3D          3D   First
1  Second                        Wireless    Wireless  Second
2                 Three        Accounting  Accounting   Three
3                        Four       cisco       cisco    Four
```

Finally you can remove the cols that are not required.

```
cols_to_del = ['Second','First','Three','Four']
f = f[f.columns.difference(cols_to_del)]
```

Final df will be:

```
In [9]: f                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[9]: 
           cl     new          pi
0          3D   First          3D
1    Wireless  Second    Wireless
2  Accounting   Three  Accounting
3       cisco    Four       cisco
```

Answer (score 0):

Data; Generated own data because could not use images.

import pandas as pd

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['nvidia','cisco','amazon'],'primary_sector':['Manufacturing','Entertainment','Others']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'category lists':['3D','Accounting','nvidia', 'cisco', 'wireless','nvidia','3D','amazon'], 'sales':[100,300,34,67,890,189,567,78]})
```

df2

Put df name and primary_sector in dictionary

```
 dicto=dict(zip(df['name'],df['primary_sector']))
dicto
```

Map dicto to df2

```
df2['sector']=df2['category lists'].map(dicto)
df2
```

Output

[image]